# creating ListView in webApp

Tags: javascript, web, ember.js, web-applications, ember-cli

Is there any way I could create a listview on a web app build using ember?
I could use css overflow property on a  tag to create a scroll-able section. But I want to load data on demand on-to that section of window, unlike with 'overflow' that will fetch all data onLoad only. It should be more alike as in android ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this is possible. You can analyze the scroll position, and then load data. But I would strongly recommend you to checkout [smoke and mirrors](https://github.com/runspired/smoke-and-mirrors), which is an addon that does exactly what you need.